# HTML Form to GoogleSheets using Google-Apps-Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets, forms

I can't get data to go to the correct sheet when using google-apps-scripts to send HTML Form data to a GoogleSheets document. I do have the data being written to the google sheet so I'm certain that I'm updating the gs app correctly when I do but only one of the sheets works at any time. I can't get the data from my second form page to go to a separate sheet.

I'm a second semester college student, so I don't completely understand everything I'm using, some sections are from tutorials others are from my teacher's input(he's curious to see if I can get this to work) and the form is just from 10 minutes with the bootstrap template just to do basic testing.

I'm open to all suggestions to help with this, but I'd be grateful if it is easily expanded to be able to incorporate more tabs later in the project.
Thank you for your time.

> meetingeventtracker.html - form section  fundrasingrequest.html is
>   basically the same thing but with different ids and names

```
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" id="orgNameMET" name="orgNameMET" class="form-control-md form-control inputs" placeholder="Enter Organization Name">
                <input type="text" id="repNameMET" name="repNameMET" class="form-control-md form-control inputs" placeholder="Enter Name of Representative">
                <input type="email" id="repEmailMET" name="repEmailMET" class="form-control-md form-control inputs" placeholder="Enter Email of Representative">
                <input type="date" id="dateOfMeeting" name="dateOfMeeting" class="form-control-md form-control inputs" placeholder="Enter Date of Meeting/Event">
                <input type="time" id="timeOfEvent" name="timeOfEvent" class="form-control-md form-control inputs" placeholder="Enter Time of Meeting/Event">
                <input type="number" id="meetingCosts" name="meetingCosts" class="form-control-md form-control inputs" placeholder="Enter Cost of Meeting">
                <input type="text" id="futureEvents" name="futureEvents" class="form-control-md form-control inputs" placeholder="Enter Future Events">
                <input type="text" id="ifFund" name="ifFund" class=form-control-md form-control inputs="IF fundraiser" value="meet" style="opacity: 0;">
                <button type="submit">Submit Data</button>
            </div>
```

> google-sheets.js   what i'm using to send the data from the forms to
>   the script

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

// Variable to hold request
var request;
$("#foo").submit(function(event){
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    var $form = $(this);
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, button");
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzc9hr7HFK10LBVP_UnOvVyUsTDslD4GBq50olyGdP5br6TBkE/exec",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        console.log(response);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    request.always(function () {
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

> Code.gs   the google apps script, I don't know what the parameter would be to get the app to switch tabs in the sheets depending on which form was submitted

```
var tabs = [
    'MeetingEventTracker',
    'FundRaisingRequest'
];

//var SHEET_NAME = tabs[1];

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
function doGet(e) {
    return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e) {
    return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
    var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
    lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.
    try {
      var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));

      for (i = 0; i < 12; i++ ){
        if (e.parameter[i] = "meet") {
            var SHEET_NAME = tabs[1];
        } else if (e.parameter[i] = "fund") {
            var SHEET_NAME = tabs[0];
        }
      }
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
        var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
        var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // get next row
        var row = [];
        // loop through the header columns
        for (i in headers) {

            if (headers[i] == "Timestamp") {
                row.push(new Date());
            } else {

                row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
            }
        }
        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
        return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
                "result": "success",
                "row": nextRow,
            }))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    } catch (e) {
        return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
                "result": "error",
                "error": e,              
            }))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    } finally { //release lock
        lock.releaseLock();
    }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Comment: Where is `#foo`?

Comment: hi, I don't know what that means, I'm basically teaching myself most of this. most of the code is what I was able to put together from tutorials or my teacher's advice so I don't have the most complete knowledge of any of the technologies used.

Comment: You wrote in your JavaScript `var request;
$("#foo").submit(function(event){` but there is `no id="foo"` in your html. Also the $ suggests that your using JQuery, so have you loaded the resources for JQuery?